# Declare an array in a typescript interface and model

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to typescript, i am trying to a add list attribute to an interface and a model class like this:

```
export class Data {
  number: number;
  list: []; // my list

constructor(rawData?: RawData) {
    if (rawData) {
    this.number = rawData.number;
    this.list= rawData.list;
  }
 }
}
```

and here :

```
  export interface RawData {
   number: number;
   list: [];
 }
```

but i am facing this error:

```
  A tuple type element list cannot be empty
```

when launching tests where i mock this model like this:

```
{[key: string]: Data} = {
  [january]: {'number': 19, 'list': null},
  [february]: {'number': 18, 'list': null},
 }
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: What type is your list ? You can do : `int[]`, `string[]`, ...

Comment: `list: []`is your problem, after the : you should define a type, not the value, like string[]

Comment: Or you can use `any[]` if you wish to keep typeless.

Comment: ```export interface RawData {
   number: number;
   list: any[];
 }```


Use this it should fix your problem.

Comment: It works i typed the attribute. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

**Define list property with `?` if it is an optional property of `RawData` `interface`.**

```
export interface RawData {
   number: number;
   list?: [];
}
```

Comment: Your solution won't solve OP problem, when you define an interface you should define the attributes (list) and its type (string/number or array of that types). Using only `[]` you are making an assignment of an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try by initializing the array and `concat` the new array

```
export class Data {
            number: number;
            list: any[] = []; // my list

            constructor(rawData?: RawData) {
                if (rawData) {
                  this.number = rawData.number;
                  this.list.concat(rawData.list);
                }

            }
        }
```